Using add-to-list with a list passed as a function arg
I need to build a function that, among other things, modifies, using add-to-list, a list that is passed as an argument to the function itself. I understand that the list passed as an argument is interpreted as a copy of the original list, but how do I modify the original list within the function? Is it possible?
The problem is that such a function isn't designed to return the list value, but rather the modification of that variable should persist even outside the function itself.
Why this code works:
(defun my-working-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((MYLIST '()))
    (add-to-list 'MYLIST "foo" t)
    (add-to-list 'MYLIST "bar" t)
    (message "%S" MYLIST)))
;; returns: ("foo" "bar") 

while this other one don't?:
(defun my-add-string-to-list (LIST STRING)
  (add-to-list 'LIST STRING t)
  (buffer-string)) ;; just to show that the function does not returns LIST

(defun my-failing-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((MYLIST '()))
    (my-add-string-to-list MYLIST "foo")
    (my-add-string-to-list MYLIST "bar")
    (message (format "%s" MYLIST))))
;; returns: nil

I can't figure out how or whether to quote the MYLIST variable.
Edit. I edited my-add-string-to-list just to suggest that it doesn't return the LIST value.

Does this answer your question? How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?

@Drew Today I understood something more about the mechanism of quoting... but I'll need to study more and your suggestion will be very useful to me. Thank you.

You can do it with a function - you don't need a macro:
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my-add-string-to-list (LIST-VAR STRING)
    (add-to-list LIST-VAR STRING t)
    (buffer-string)) ;; just to show that the function does not returns LIST

  (defun my-failing-test ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((MYLIST '()))
      (my-add-string-to-list 'MYLIST "foo")
      (my-add-string-to-list 'MYLIST "bar")
      (message (format "%S" MYLIST))))

  (my-failing-test)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: (foo bar)

You just need to pass the unevaluated symbol down to my-add-string-to-list (and from there to add-to-list).

I tried but I get: my-add-string-to-list: Symbol’s value as variable is void: MYLIST.

Make sure that you copied the code correctly (BTW, I changed the format to "%S" which will improve the output a bit), then put just the code in a file /tmp/foo.el and then say emacs -Q /tmp/foo.el - I get ("foo" "bar") as the result.

This is strange to me: If I evaluate the functions with eval-defun (I tried inverting the order of evaluation) the code doesn't work. If I do evaluate-buffer the code works. It never happened to me.

There is something wrong in your setup. Try starting with emacs -Q, then open /tmp/foo.el, evaluate the two defuns in whatever order you want and then evaluate the my-failing-test call. Both orders work the same and they both work.

I found it happens in the *scratch* buffer. If I start Emacs without the -Q option and I open the /tmp/foo.el file, all is ok. If i switch to the scratch buffer and I evaluate again the same functions I get again the same error. Should I open another issue to clarify this point?

If it does not happen with emacs -Q, but it happens when you start emacs normally, then it's a problem with your init file: bisect it to figure out the culprit - see Step 2 in the link.

I happens also with emacs -Q. I'll open a separate issue.

I solved using defmacro:
(defmacro my-add-string-to-list (LIST STRING)
  `(progn
     (add-to-list ,LIST ,STRING t)
     (buffer-string)))

(defun my-failing-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((MYLIST '()))
    (my-add-string-to-list 'MYLIST "foo")
    (my-add-string-to-list 'MYLIST "bar")
    (message (format "%S" MYLIST))))

